# Content Management System assigning padding to an element - Can I override?

Tags: jquery, css, content-management-system, padding

I am working on a CMS that I cannot edit the overall css classes, only code that is in template placeholders. Using Firefox web developer inspector, I have identified the name of the class that is adding the padding to the box but can't figure out how to override it as it is assigned after the page is rendered.

Is there code I can add to the page to displace the class and more specifically just the padding? I'm trying to embed a twitter feed with a min size of 180px in a box that is 183px but has 10px of padding.

Site uses jQuery 1.8.1 if that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to provide the name of the CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the element in your template, try adding a `style="padding: 10px !important"`